# 1 experimental group - 6 control groups: ANOVA or t-tests or something else?

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, anova, t-test, experiment-design

Objective: I want to find out, if a certain machine learning algorithm can select the right 100 stocks out of my stock universe of 2.000 stocks, such that they achieve better combined yearly returns than my control groups / benchmarks.

**Experimental group**: the portfolio that was selected through the machine learning algorithm

Control Group 1: benchmark 1 (e.g. S&P 500)

Control Group 2: benchmark 2

Control Group 3: benchmark 3

Control Group 4: benchmark 4

Control Group 5: benchmark 5

Control Group 6: Same setup as with the experimental group, however using an old machine learning algorithm.

**Question 1**: What is the right approach, if I really just want to compare my experimental group to each of the control groups. I am not interested in the variances between the control groups. The only thing I am interested in is if the returns are higher in a statistically significant manner. Do I use ANOVA, pair-wise t-tests or something else?

**Question 2**: If building contrasts and ANOVA is the right approach, do I have to use a repeat measure ANOVA? The problem is that I comparing portfolios of stocks, which may or may not overlap. Additionally the stocks in these portfolios may change over time.

If anything from the above is confusing, please tell me what I should clarify. Thank you in advance

Comment: What are you using to verify if the performance of your portfolio?  The past 10 years?  Quarterly Data?  Or perhaps are you just looking at the performance at the end of a the year?

Comment: Could you explain why you are not concerned about the variation exhibited between the control groups?  That would be an extremely important aspect of most meaningful analyses of these data.

Comment: @StatsStudent I am using yearly returns for the past 5 years. So that I have 5 data points per group.

Comment: @whuber: hm, my thinking was: all my hypotheses are centered around, if my experimental group performs better than the control groups. I didn't think that a variation between the control groups would be relevant as these are not useful for answering my hypotheses,or is it? E.g. if control group 1 is the S&P 500 and control group 2 is a Value ETF - would it really be interesting for readers that I analyze the variation beween those two? Having said that, I am a newb to doing research - therefore, if my thinking is wrong, please go ahead and explain where I am wrong.

Comment: Such groups are expected to differ in substantial ways in terms of their financial performance, statistical characteristics, and what they actually mean.  This suggests that you do not have multiple control groups, but rather multiple questions you are asking concerning various differences among the six groups.

Comment: @whuber - okay, if they are not control groups and rather multiple questions, what would be the right approach to answer these questions? Is it with post-hoc tests or should I still look to do an ANOVA?

Comment: I don't know, because it's unclear how the concept of "statistically significant" might apply here.  In what sense are your groups random samples of anything?

Comment: hm - you are right, there are no "random" samples. But what I have are samples built by certain rules. E.g. S&P 500 rule is to take the top 500 companies by market capitalization and create a portfolio. A Value ETF might take the top 500 companies based on P/E ratio. Basically each group is doing sampling based on different rules....does it not make sense to ask if the returns are really a statistically significant deviation of what you could have gotten from the S&P 500 and not just a random variation?